# Exploring json with command lines

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, jq

Can someone helps me finding out a solution for this problem with a command line?
Here's my Json file :

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ShelfEx »position,
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "shopId",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      },
      "doc": "Id of the shop"
    },
    {
      "name": "productId",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      },
      "doc": "Id of the product"
    },
    {
      "name": "sourceId",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      },
      "doc": "Id of the source"
    },
    {
      "name": "timestampTransmission",
      "type": "long",
      "doc": "Timestamp of the message"
    },
    {
      "name": "productQuantity",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "double"
      ],
      "doc": "Quantity of the product",
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

and i want to get the name of each field, with it's type and eventually it's default value (null in the case of productQuantity).
So the output should but something like :

```
"shopId" string
"productId" string
...
"timestampTransmission" long
"productQuantity" double null
```

Any idea please?

```
`cat file.json | jq -r '.fields[] | "\"\(.name)\" : \(.type | tostring | sub("^(null)$"; "\\1 :     null") | sub("(^\"|\"$)"; ""))"'`
```

Instead of :

```
"shopId" string
"productId" string
...
"timestampTransmission" long
"productQuantity" double null
```

i had :

```
"shopId" : {"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}
"productId" : {"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}
"sourceId" : {"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"}
"timestampTransmission" : long
"productQuantity" : ["null","double"]
```

Comment: You need to fix your JSON: `parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 4, column 3`

Comment: This is `ShelfEx »position` the issue, you never close quotes

Comment: Is your code really inside backticks? Or did you put code markdown inside a code block?

Comment: Each question should be about _one_ narrow, specific problem. Please fix your code so it demonstrates the issue you want us to help with, as opposed to having other problems along the way.

Comment: It looks like you're asking how to _use_ jq, rather than anything to do with writing a program, hence outside scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your formatting, you want

```bash
.fields[] | [

  # .name in quotes (what about escaping?)
  "\"\(.name)\"",

  # .type.type or .type[] or .type as a scalar, filtering out null
  (.type | objects.type // arrays[] // . | select(. != "null")),

  # .default, only if it exists
  (select(has("default")).default | tostring)

] | join(" ")
```

Use it as `jq -r '…' file.json` to get

```
"shopId" string
"productId" string
"sourceId" string
"timestampTransmission" long
"productQuantity" double null
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_MrnovCuE9m)